# Flutter.h Not Found, Url_launcher _ios problem

Tags: flutter, xcode

[image: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found /Users/apple/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.0.17/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4:8]

I'm Stuck last 2 days, I have tried many solutions but still stuck please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you tried to delete ur podfile.lock and pod install again ?

Comment: yes I have deleted podfile, podfile.lock, Flutter.podspec but still issue